# Dependency issue using viva connections extension in VS code

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, error, microsoft-viva

I have installed the Viva connections extension in VS code. When I create a new project I get this error:

```
[2023-04-26T19:04:44.654Z] [INFO]
Running command: yo @microsoft/sharepoint --solution-name "vivasolution1" --component-type adaptiveCardExtension --aceTemplateType Basic --component-name "HelloWorld" --skip-install 
Error @microsoft/sharepoint --solution-name vivasolution1 --component-type adaptiveCardExtension --aceTemplateType Basic --component-name HelloWorld --skip-install 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name “@microsoft/sharepoint” installed.
But help is on the way:

You can see available generators via npm search yeoman-generator or via http://yeoman.io/generators/. 
Install them with npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint.

To see all your installed generators run yo --generators. Adding the --help option will also show subgenerators. 

If yo cannot find the generator, run yo doctor to troubleshoot your system.
[2023-04-26T19:08:38.346Z] [INFO]
```

**But I do have it installed.**

```
PS1> yo --generators
Available Generators:

  @microsoft/sharepoint
    adaptiveCardExtension
    applicationCustomizer
    commandSet
    component
    extension
    fieldCustomizer
    formCustomizer
    library
    searchQueryModifier
    solution
    webpart
PS1>
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the extension, no luck.  Have not rebooted yet.

Not sure what to do with this?

Comment: Did you install it globally, like: `npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint -g`. Also, try restarting the system after installing npm packages and VS code extension.

Comment: I did use the -g switch.  I have not rebooted.  brb

Comment: Reboot seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: I have added it as an answer below with some steps. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps for resolve this issue:

1. Install SPFx yeoman generator globally:

   Use below command:

   ```
   npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint -g
   ```
2. Install Microsoft Viva Connections extension in Visual Studio code
3. Restart your system and Visual studio code.